# Algorithm for Generation of Wallets

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, viewkey, privatekey, spend-key

I am interested in the full algorithm for the generation of Monero wallets from seed words. I am looking for as much detail as possible.

Can anyone point in the direction of the most complete documentation or place I should start?

I am struggling to find anything other then https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator and sorting through the source code.

EDIT: Found this as well https://github.com/taushet/monerobrainwallet/blob/master/site/js/base58.js
EDIT 2: https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html
This is closer to what I want but lacking implementation details

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/skaht/XMR.  Can use either Electrum or BIP 39 seed words.  Also look at https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#10-monero-xmr-bip-3944-technology-examples.